# How to observe a Core Data relationship before it gets actually changed?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data, nsarraycontroller

I am trying to find a way of observing a Core Data relationship (more specifically the removed items of an unordered relationship) before it gets actually changed. You can imagine it as a *"will change"* notification known from other Cocoa APIs.

The reason is that I want to update the UI according to these changes and I need a parameter which isn't stored in the managed objects but in an other data structure (in my case it's the index from a `NSArrayController`). I can retrieve the parameter only if the items weren't removed from the relationship yet.

The only way of getting such *"will change"* notifications I could find was to override the KVO method `-willChangeValueForKey:withSetMutation:usingObjects:` in the custom `NSManagedObject` subclass and forward this information. The problem is [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/willChangeValueForKey%3awithSetMutation%3ausingObjects%3a) says: *"You must not override this method."* and this makes me want to find a better solution.

1. Is the *"will change"* approach right in this case?
2. If so, how could I achieve it? If not, how should I solve the mentioned problem in another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just override the relationship’s setter method instead.

Comment: To be exact, I am going to override the mutation methods, not the setter, but that's the way to go! Thanks!

Comment: You wrote: "The reason is that I want to update the UI according to these changes " - So now you are modifying your UI from your model code? Btw: Hi Wil! :D